# How to check if JEnumerable list is empty

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm deserializing a Json as:

```
    var tokens = new JEnumerable<JToken>();

    var eventJson = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("someJsonXpath", false);

    if(eventJson != null)
        tokens = eventJson.Children();
```

The problem is, when eventJson  is null, tokens object becomes empty. I'm trying to check if the tokens  is empty or not.

I have tried

```
tokens == null
Object.Equals(tokens,null)
tokens.Equals(null)
```

they returns *false*. *tokens.Count()* returns null reference exception. Is there any good way to check that?

Comment: "tokens.Count() returns null reference exception" --- That is strange. But try `tokens.Any()` this is used for checking empty collections.

Comment: Why are you not validating this?! O.o

Comment: @Habib it's same. tokens.Any() throws null reference too.

Comment: @FelipeKM that's what i am trying to do :) How do i validate it?

Comment: `tokens` and `eventTokens` in your code, are they the same thing?

Comment: @DavidG yes, sorry forgot to edit it. Editing now.

Comment: I feel like we are missing something critical here.

Comment: There is something not right if `tokens == null` is false and it is still throwing a NRE.  Can you post a complete reproducible example and specify exactly what line the error occurs on.

Comment: `tokens` will never be null, as you initialize it with new JEnumerable<...>, so Count() should not throw null reference. I guess there must be something else going on, post your code, in a form where the problem is reproducable.

Comment: @vgSefa, The problem is the line `tokens = eventJson.Children();`, The method `Children` is returning `null`, in your check add an extra condition like `if(eventJson != null && eventJson.Children() != null)`

Comment: @Habib `tokens = eventJson.Children()` returns `JEnumerable<JToken>.Empty`, if there are no children, and that's ok. The problem occurs when the `eventJson` variable is null. In that case `tokens` variable is not initialized correctly. It is an internal logic of the `JEnumerable<T>` class.

Answer (score 3):

Change the initialization of `tokens` variable from:

```
var tokens = new JEnumerable<JToken>();
```

to

```
var tokens = JEnumerable<JToken>.Empty;
```

After this the `Any()` and `Count()` extension methods will not throw exceptions.